# Include original URL from Excel sheet in scrapy output

Tags: python, scrapy, export-to-csv

I'm using Scrapy to crawl some pages. I refer to an excel sheet for the start_urls, and I want those *exact* start urls to appear in the results, rather than the redirected urls. I need the originals in order to process Excel lookups.

The problem is that I only seem to be able to get an output that gives the destination url.

My code is as follows;

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from ICcom5.items import ICcom5Item
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from scrapy.spiders import CSVFeedSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import requests
import csv
import sys

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "ICcom5"
    start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open('items5.csv').readlines()]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = Item()
        titles = response.xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter"]')
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = ICcom5Item()
            home_url = ("http://www.indeed.co.uk")
            item ['_pageURL'] = response.request.url
            item ['description'] = ' '.join(titles.xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"]//text()').extract())
            item ['role_title_link'] = titles.xpath('//span[@id="originalJobLinkContainer"]/a/@href').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Pretty simple code, but I'm struggling to understand what I can do from the Scrapy docs.

---

I have modified the code according to advice but I'm still not getting the original urlsfrom my source spreadsheet. Example urls are as follows;

```
https://www.indeed.co.uk/rc/clk?jk=a47eb72131f3d588&fccid=c7414b794cb89c1c&vjs=3
https://www.indeed.co.uk/rc/clk?jk=8c7f045caddb116d&fccid=473601b0f30a6c9c&vjs=3
https://www.indeed.co.uk/company/Agilysts-Limited/jobs/Back-End-Java-Developer-3ec6efc3ebc256c5?fccid=d1f7896a8bd9f15e&vjs=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `response.request.url` in the `parse` function to get the original URL you requested.

**UPDATE:** I either understand [the documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.request) wrong or it's a bug. Specifically

> HTTP redirections will cause the original request (to the URL before redirection) to be assigned to the redirected response (with the final URL after redirection)

makes me really think that the original request URL should be available under `response.request.url`.

Anyway, as stated in the [`RedirectMiddleware` documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware), there's an alternative way. You can use `redirect_urls` key of the `request.meta` to get a list of URLs the request goes through. So here's the modified (simplified) version of your code as a PoC:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.indeed.co.uk/rc/clk?jk=a47eb72131f3d588&fccid=c7414b794cb89c1c&vjs=3',
        'https://www.indeed.co.uk/rc/clk?jk=8c7f045caddb116d&fccid=473601b0f30a6c9c&vjs=3',
        'https://www.indeed.co.uk/company/Agilysts-Limited/jobs/Back-End-Java-Developer-3ec6efc3ebc256c5?fccid=d1f7896a8bd9f15e&vjs=3'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter"]'):
            item = {}
            redirect_urls = response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls')
            item['_pageURL'] = redirect_urls[0] if redirect_urls else response.request.url
            item['description'] = ' '.join(title.xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"]//text()').extract())
            item['role_title_link'] = title.xpath('//span[@id="originalJobLinkContainer"]/a/@href').extract()
            yield item
```

Also, note that there are some other issues with your original code you provided, specifically:

- in your `parse` method, you are returning `items` which is a `list` but only `dict` is allowed (or `Item` or `Request`)
- the line `for titles in titles:` probably does something you didn't intend

Comment: Thanks Tomáš, However, I modified my code as you directed, and my scrape still returned the redirected url rather than the url from my source spreadsheet. I changed the line `item ['_pageURL'] = start.urls` to `item ['_pageURL'] = response.request.url`. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct. There's a [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.request) for using this too. I use it commonly and works as expected. I suspect other issues. Could you share complete code and at least a snippet (one or two) URLs causing problems?

Comment: Hi Tomáš. I've modified the code in my original question to reflect the full script and added some recent urls examples. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for persevering  Tomáš, your coding suggestion worked. Very helpful. I will post my final code, so other people can see the difference from my original.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final working code, with the help of Tomáš Linhart

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "ICcom5"
    start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open('items5.csv').readlines()]
    def parse(self, response):
        item = Item()

        for titles in response.xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter"]'):
            items = []
            item = ICcom5Item()
            redirect_urls = response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls')
            item['_pageURL'] = redirect_urls[0] if redirect_urls else response.request.url
            item ['description'] = ' '.join(titles.xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"]//text()').extract())
            item ['role_title_link'] = titles.xpath('//span[@id="originalJobLinkContainer"]/a/@href').extract()

            items.append(item)
        return items
```